# Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource

Tags: spring-boot, h2, flyway

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: No value provided for placeholder expressions: ${ifMySQL}.  Check your configuration!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1778) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:307) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:742) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:389) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1213) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1202) [spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at 
Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: No value provided for placeholder expressions: ${ifMySQL}.  Check your configuration!
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.placeholder.DefaultPlaceholderReplacer.checkForUnmatchedPlaceholderExpression(DefaultPlaceholderReplacer.java:101) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.placeholder.DefaultPlaceholderReplacer.replacePlaceholders(DefaultPlaceholderReplacer.java:79) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.line.PlaceholderReplacingLine.<init>(PlaceholderReplacingLine.java:25) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.sqlscript.SqlScript.extractStatements(SqlScript.java:108) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.sqlscript.SqlScript.<init>(SqlScript.java:86) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.resolver.sql.SqlMigrationResolver.addMigrations(SqlMigrationResolver.java:140) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.resolver.sql.SqlMigrationResolver.resolveMigrations(SqlMigrationResolver.java:100) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.resolver.sql.SqlMigrationResolver.resolveMigrations(SqlMigrationResolver.java:47) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.resolver.CompositeMigrationResolver.collectMigrations(CompositeMigrationResolver.java:136) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.resolver.CompositeMigrationResolver.doFindAvailableMigrations(CompositeMigrationResolver.java:118) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.resolver.CompositeMigrationResolver.resolveMigrations(CompositeMigrationResolver.java:104) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.resolver.CompositeMigrationResolver.resolveMigrations(CompositeMigrationResolver.java:46) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.info.MigrationInfoServiceImpl.refresh(MigrationInfoServiceImpl.java:133) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbValidate$2.call(DbValidate.java:138) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbValidate$2.call(DbValidate.java:126) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:74) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbValidate.validate(DbValidate.java:126) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.doValidate(Flyway.java:1476) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.access$100(Flyway.java:85) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:1364) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:1356) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:1711) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:1356) ~[flyway-core-5.2.4.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(FlywayMigrationInitializer.java:65) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
```

***I tried:***

1. removing all the tags ifmysql,
2. using older version of Springboot - 1.5.17 and using flyway version 4.2.0, still the error is same.
3. using Springboot 2.x and using flyway version 4.2.0 and 5.2.0
4. changing h2 db version to 1.4.199

Comment: Show your properties file